# Ash script - detect whether a variable equals to "?"

Tags: string, shell, switch-statement, ash

I am writing an Ash script and trying to detect whether an input variable equals to "?" or not. I found out that it is best to use `case` for doing this, but I can't manage to get this working. My code is:

```
case $@ in
*?*) usage
    operationSucceeded
    exit;;
  *) echo "Unknown argument: $@"
    usage
    operationFailed
    exit $E_OPTERROR;;   # DEFAULT\
esac
```

The first option always gets triggered, while I want it to trigger only when `?` is the variable, and the other option for everything else.

Comment: `?` is a wildcard that matches any single character, much like `*` matches zero or more characters -- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to

```
 case $@ in
     *[\?]* ) usage 
    .....
  easc
```

You  may not need the '\' , but it can't hurt.

In the more general sense, `[ABC]` is called a character class, and will match any of the single chars listed inside `[ ]`. So in `*[\?]*`, we're saying "any number of characters (including zero chars), followed by the Char class `[\?]` (in this case, only the '?' char), followed by zero or more characters".

IHTH

Comment: Yes, the backslash is not required.